# How can I find patent number 2208003.0?

Tags: patent-infringement, patent-applications, design-patent, trademark

I am interested in selling a product but an other seller (on their website) claims that this product is patented. I have contacted the seller and  he says

"Our patent number is 2208003.0. This is still pending with the UK IPO but it already protects our product from being copied worldwide."

But I cant find any patent with this number...

Comment: Can you please check the application number. It doesn’t seem to be a normal format.

Comment: Closest thing I could find is https://patents.google.com/patent/EP2208003A2/en?oq=Uk+2208003 which has a status of withdrawn.

Comment: Alternatively there is a Great Britain patent application https://patents.google.com/patent/GB2208003A/en?oq=gb+2208003 which was granted but has expired.

Comment: I am wonder what product you want to sell, or there are several patents with the same applicate number.